# How to pass N parameters / arguments to pm2?

Tags: pm2

I need to start my node with pm2 passing 2 paremeters: the config file and the port number

Equivalent to

```
node server.js ./config.json 9000
```

I tried that:

```
pm2 start server.js --name server1 -- ./config.json -- 9000
```

The second parameter is never passed.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this below without -- parameter on each argument. After first -- parameter we can pass multiple arguments by space seperated.

```
pm2 start server.js --name server1 -- ./config.json 9000
```